# Django Haystack connection error using http authentication

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack, http-authentication, pyelasticsearch

I'm using Haystack to connect and interact with an installation of elasticsearch. Elasticsearch is installed on a different box to the main webserver.

I have set up HTTP authentication on the elasticsearch box using nginx. This is to stop unauthorised access to elasticsearch.

The Haystack config looks like this:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@DOMAIN:PORT/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}
```

With this set up I get a connection error:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(('Connection aborted.',
gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))) caused by: ProtocolError(('Connection
aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known')))
```

If I turn off HTTP authentication and update the URL correspondingly to `http://DOMAIN:PORT/` it connects without a problem.

Could it be that Haystack (or elasticsearch-py (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/) doesn't allow HTTP authentication to be used in the URL? I notice this is a problem with Solr - [Solr authentication (using Django Haystack)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492694/solr-authentication-using-django-haystack)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For others with the same problem, add kwargs to config:

```
'KWARGS': {
    'port': parsed.port,
    'http_auth': (parsed.username, parsed.password),
}
```

See: https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1046